# Make size of multicombo box and items same

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a multicombo box with items inside it. Currently, width of combo box and items is not equal:

[image: current version]

I want to make width of both elements same, like this:

[image: this]

I had tried

```
<MultiComboBox width="auto">
<items>
<core:Item key="ac" text="ac"/>
</items>
</MultiComboBox>
```

also this

```
<MultiComboBox width="100%">
<items>
<core:Item key="ac" text="ac"/>
</items>
</MultiComboBox>
```

and this

```
<MultiComboBox>
<items width="100%">
<core:Item key="ac" text="ac"/>
</items>
</MultiComboBox>
```

However, nothing is working. Can anyone suggest me something?

Comment: I suppose this is a standard behavior that the with of suggestions depends on the content of suggestion but not on the with of the input field. Why is it critical for you?

Comment: Was a requirement of client. But as you said, it makes more sense that width should be equal to content. Thanks.

Comment: Unable to replicate on 1.44.13. Can you tell me your UI5 version and more of your page layout?

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj try newer version, after 1.44

Comment: @BellaAndrew: tried on 1.46.12. Still Unable to replicate. :(. Can you please create same scenario in pluckr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can do this. That's the trick: MultiComboBox has a hidden aggregation **picker**, which you can obtain by function **getPicker**. It returns a sap.m.Popover instance which in turn has 2 properties (contentWidth and contentMinWidth) and even beforeOpen. The trick is to set contentWidth or contentMinWidth in the beforeOpen event.

See code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="description" content="UI5 table example with local JSON model" />
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
 
 <title>UI5 Table Example</title>
 
 <!-- Load UI5, select gold reflection theme and the "commons" and "table" control libraries -->
 <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript'
  src='https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
  data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
  data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m,sap.ui.core'></script>

  <script>
          var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel([
            { key: "0", text: "First item text"},
            { key: "1", text: "Second item text"},
            { key: "2", text: "Third item text"},
            { key: "3", text: "Fourth item text"},
            { key: "4", text: "Fifth item text"},
            { key: "5", text: "Sixth item text"},
            { key: "6", text: "Seventh item text"},
          ]);
          
          var  oSelect = new sap.m.MultiComboBox("testSelect", {
            width: "15rem",
            items: { 
                      path: 'items>/', 
                      templateShareable: false, 
                      template: new sap.ui.core.Item({ key: '{items>key}', text: '{items>text}'})
                   }
          });
          
          oSelect.setModel(oModel, "items");
          
          // The trick - setting of contentWidth or contentMinWidth of Combobox Dropdown list
          
          var oPicker = oSelect.getPicker();
          if (oPicker) {
            oPicker.attachBeforeOpen(function() {
              // oPicker.setContentWidth(oSelect.getWidth()); // Item texts can be cut
              oPicker.setContentMinWidth(oSelect.getWidth());
            });
          } else {
            console.error("Picker is empty");
          }
          
          oSelect.placeAt("content");
  </script>
 </head>
 <body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
 </body>
</html>
```